# Redirection in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am using angular js for a project, I have a login page, from where upon successful login the user is redirected to homepage. As of now i am using this code to redirect

```
request.success(function(data){
              $scope.response=data;
              NProgress.done();
              window.location.href = "/app/home.html";
             //$location.path('/homepage').replace();
        });
```

But the problem with this method is that the url in the browser shows **/app/home.html#/feed**  which doesn't look good. I want this to achieve through routeprovider in angular but it is not working. 
My current app.js file looks like this

```
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/feed', {templateUrl: 'partials/home/feed.html'});
$routeProvider.when('/profile', {templateUrl: 'partials/home/profile2.html'});
//  $routeProvider.when('/homepage', {templateUrl: '#/home.html'});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/feed'});
```

I want the url in the broswer to look like **app/homepage/feed** using $location as i have tried in the comments. Any idea how i might be able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The function `$locationProvider.html5Mode(boolean)` is what you need.
Just do `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and you shouldn't see any `#`s anymore.

It is on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) of the documentation

Comment: My problem isn't **#** i don't want the file extension .html to be visible in the browser,  currently i am using $locationProvider.html5Mode(boolean) but have kept it false as i first want to remove the .html from the url

Comment: What does a file extension have to do with routing? What happens if you try what I suggested? @Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using Server Side Language/Routing,only you are using angularJs. then simply add this to completly remove # tag from angular.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

But if you are using server side language then you will have to create a catch-all route so that any routes that are not specifically routed at server-side will be passed to angular routes.i am using here express server as a backend to catch route which are not mentioned in backend. i am assuming that you are using express.js:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.render('index');
});
```

overall your server code will look like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = module.exports = express();
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.render('index');
});
```

for detail use [this](http://masterjs.in/how-to-remove-tag-from-angular-routes-in-angular-js/) link

Comment: We are using sails.js for the backend but i got the idea anyway